# Instagram Face Extracter using Python with Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

***Github Repo :*** https://github.com/hassan-sd/insta-face-scraper

***Colab (My Code) :*** https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1excrJPU1F3Dv5inZhofni-MGHVIYzCW-?usp=sharing

**My Google Colab Code :**

```
# Step 1: Clone the Repository
!git clone https://github.com/hassan-sd/insta-face-scraper.git

# Display completion message
print("Step 1: Repository cloned successfully.")

# Step 2: Set Up the Environment
!pip install instaloader==4.8.3 && echo -e "\033[1minstaloader==4.8.3 successfully installed.\033[0m"
!pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66 && echo -e "\033[1mopencv-python==4.6.0.66 successfully installed.\033[0m"
!pip install dlib==19.22.1 && echo -e "\033[1mdlib==19.22.1 successfully installed.\033[0m"
!pip install face-recognition==1.3.0 && echo -e "\033[1mface-recognition==1.3.0 successfully installed.\033[0m"
!pip install scikit-learn==1.0 && echo -e "\033[1mscikit-learn==1.0 successfully installed.\033[0m"
!pip install numpy==1.21.4 && echo -e "\033[1mnumpy==1.21.4 successfully installed.\033[0m"
!pip install Pillow==9.0.0 && echo -e "\033[1mPillow==9.0.0 successfully installed.\033[0m"
!pip install pytesseract==0.3.8 && echo -e "\033[1mpytesseract==0.3.8 successfully installed.\033[0m"

# Display completion message
print("Step 2: Environment set up successfully.")

# Step 3: Create and Save a Value in u.txt
u_value = input("Enter a value for u.txt: ")

try:
    # Create and save the value in u.txt
    with open("insta-face-scraper/u.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(u_value)
    
    # Display completion message
    print("Step 3: Value saved successfully in u.txt.")
except Exception as e:
    # Display failure message
    print("Step 3: Failed to save value in u.txt:", str(e))

# Step 4: Execute the Code
try:
    # Run the script
    !python insta-face-scraper/hassan-insta.py
    
    # Display completion message
    print("Step 4: Execution completed successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    # Display failure message
    print("Step 4: Execution failed:", str(e))
```

Can you tell me why it not executing?. What mistake i am doing?